# how to set htaccess correct (redirect)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

All my url have the following schema:

```
domain.de/LANGUAGE/CATEGORY/PAGE.html
```

this url will be handeled through this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /?lang=$1&subid=$2&id=$3 [L,QSA]
```

so what I want is the following redirections:

```
#Start page:
domain.de -> www.domain.de/de/abc/index.html
domain.de/LANG/ -> www.domain.de/LANG/abc/index.html
www.domain.de -> www.domain.de/de/abc/index.html
wwww.domain.de/LANG/ -> www.domain.de/LANG/abc/index.html

#In general:
all pages without www should be redirected to page with www 

#subdomain
subdomain.domain.de -> www.domain.de/de/abc/xy.html
```

My start:

```
RewriteEngine On
# domain.de -> www.domain.de/de/abc/index.html
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(domain\.(de))$
RewriteRule .+ http://www.%1/%2/abc/index.html$0 [L,R=301]

# www.domain.de/de -> www.domain.de/de/abc/index.html
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.(de)$
RewriteRule ^%1/?$/abc index.html [L,R=301]

# subdomain.domain.de to http://www.domain.de/de/abc/xy.html
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.(domain\.(de))$
RewriteRule .+ http://www.%1/%2/abc/xy.html [L,R=301]
```

But now I don't know how to go on. May you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# domain.de -> www.domain.de/de/abc/index.html
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.de$ [NC]
RRewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# subdomain.domain.de to http://www.domain.de/de/abc/xy.html
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.(domain\.de)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.%1/de/abc/xy.html [L,R=301]

# www.domain.de/de -> www.domain.de/de/abc/index.html
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.de$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteRule ^(de|nl|en)/?$ /$1/de/abc/index.html [L]
```

Comment: Can you please check your error.log for above 500 error and tell me what you get there?

Comment: I think I know the problem, see my edit now. (you may get 404 now though).

Comment: My page links to domain.de/de/abc/def.html and now it tries to redirect to domain.de/de/abc/def.html/de/abc/index.html

Comment: But that can only happen if `/de/abc/def.html` is not a physical file.

Comment: I solved it with: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(de|nl|en)/$ http://www.domain.de/$1/abc/index.html [R=301,L]

Comment: Yes that will be better to make it more restrictive. Now if you think this answer has helped you in anyway pls mark it as accepted.